# How to execute a java command with interpolated arguments with Python's subprocess & Popen

Tags: python, formatting, arguments, subprocess

trying to run a java command from within python on Windows, using subprocess & Popen.

First I've defined two strings:

```
java_string = 'java -Xmx1024M -classpath .;./db2jcc.jar;./RetainSdi.zip;./jviews-chart.jar;./jviews-framework.jar l2stats CRF1426 > ' + datetime.date.today().strftime("%d/%m/%Y") + '.html'

working_dir = "C:\\Users\\IBM_ADMIN\\Desktop\\Weekly Report 2014\\"
```

then I tried to use subprocess as follows:

```
subprocess.Open([java_string], cwd=working_dir)
```

which results in a 
    "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"

I've edited the long java_string to not have the java command, like so:

```
java_string = '-Xmx1024M -classpath .;./db2jcc.jar;./RetainSdi.zip;./jviews-chart.jar;./jviews-framework.jar l2stats CRF1426 > ' + datetime.date.today().strftime("%d/%m/%Y") + '.html'
```

and then called Popen like so:

```
subprocess.Popen(['java', java_string], cwd=working_dir)
```

which results in a

> > > Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx1024M -classpath .;./db2jcc.jar;./RetainSdi.z
> > >       ip;./jviews-chart.jar;./jviews-framework.jar l2stats CRF1426 > 21/04/2014.html
> > >       Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.

which is at least a java error (so it's finding the java exec. in the %PATH%, but has to do with java seeing the entire string as a single argument? I have no idea.

What is the correct formatting here? Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to split the arguments into a list, as described in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor):

> Unless otherwise stated, it is recommended to pass args as a
>   sequence.

So instead of:

```
subprocess.Popen(['java', '-Xmx1024M -classpath . com.foo.Bar']
# Error (Invalid maximum heap size)
```

use:

```
subprocess.Popen(['java', '-Xmx1024M', '-classpath', '.', 'com.foo.Bar']
# OK
```

See also the Windows-specific [rules for converting an argument sequence](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#converting-argument-sequence).

**Updated**: If you need to use features of the shell, such as redirection to a file using `>`, then you need to include the `shell=True` argument, for example:

```
subprocess.Popen('echo foo > deleteme.txt', shell=True)
```

Or specify a `stdout` argument as described in the comment from J. F. Sebastian (copied here for convenience):

```
subprocess.call(['echo', 'foo'], stdout=open('deleteme.txt', 'wb'))
```

One note from the documentation:

> Passing shell=True can be a security hazard if combined with untrusted
>   input.

Comment: How do characters like the '>' fit into the argument list? Is it it's own argument? Thank you for the answers so far!

Comment: I have updated my answer with some examples of this.

Comment: Please, do not use a list argument and `shell=True` together. It has completely different meaning on POSIX systems. You could always use a string on Windows.

Comment: @user3434388: instead of `> deleteme.txt`, you could set `stdout` parameter e.g., `subprocess.call(['echo', 'foo'], stdout=open('deleteme.txt', 'wb'))`

Comment: Updated answer to only show the string/shell variant for Windows.